# Heroku installing play framework modules

Tags: java, module, heroku, playframework, securesocial

I'm trying to install a module on my heroku app. Running this locally (minus the `heroku run` at the start) works, but I get an error when trying to run it on Heroku.

```
heroku run play install securesocial-0.2.2
```

and here's the output

```
...
~ Do you want to install this version (y/n)? y
~ Installing module securesocial-0.2.2...
~
~ Fetching http://www.playframework.org/modules/securesocial-0.2.2.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".play/play", line 153, in <module>
    status = cmdloader.commands[play_command].execute(command=play_command, app=play_app, args=remaining_args, env=play_env, cmdloader=cmdloader)
  File "/app/.play/framework/pym/play/commands/modulesrepo.py", line 58, in execute
    install(app, args, env)
  File "/app/.play/framework/pym/play/commands/modulesrepo.py", line 378, in install
    Downloader().retrieve(fetch, archive)
  File "/app/.play/framework/pym/play/commands/modulesrepo.py", line 88, in retrieve
    try: urllib.urlretrieve(url, destination, self.progress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 91, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 241, in retrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/app/.play/modules/securesocial-0.2.2.zip'
```

What's the proper way to do this? I've been searching, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used heroku but perhaps this [step by step tutorial](http://geeks.aretotally.in/twitter-playframework-heroku) might help you out.

Comment: Thanks! looks like Heroku automatically resolves dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

After you add the module locally you should be able to add the changes that are made to git and then push a new version of your app to Heroku.